# Is nginx-rtmp encrypt the whole HLS fragments once?

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I want to use `nginx-rtmp-module` , By setting `hls_keys on` we can enable HLS encryption

How it works? it is encrypted one time? or encrypted per viewer session on demand?